# cannot understand the following code in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
```

The above is the code i am reffering to for the following questions:

- where to get the values for setType method? Like here they have used "vnd.android.cursor.item/event".
- For values that go into the putExtra field...like they have used over here **rrule**,**endtime** etc. How to know which strings can be used over here?
- In the above code , what does the field **rrule** stand for?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i can see, this code is related to calendar event creation.

rrule is a repetition rule, see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt

**EDIT** It seems like there are no documentation on that and a only one way is to inspect platform code.

Comment: what are the keys that i can pass in the putExtra method (my second question).

Comment: I don't actually know =(. I've tryed to examine platform sources but have found only `beginTime` and `endTime` constants in `android.provider.Calendar`. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/provider/Calendar.java The Intent to handle `vnd.android.cursor.item/event` type is `EditEvent` - http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/calendar/EditEvent.java